# Access session variables from JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, session, variables

Is it possible to access session variables made in from JavaScript, and how can I replicate this PHP code in JavaScript?

```
if(empty($_SESSION['name'] {
   echo 'foo';
}
```

Comment: The point of using session variables is that they are not visible to client side...

Comment: Its a bit of a shame, are there any disadvantages to being able to access them??

Comment: If one could arbitrarily check their session variables from the browser there could be some issues if there is data that is really meant to be hidden instead of "foo".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could access a page via Ajax which would return the variable value:

Using jQuery:

```
$.get('myVariable.php', function ( data ) {
    alert(data)
});
```

And the PHP page (myVariable.php):

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you setup your javascript to be parsed by php, you can access session vars just like you can in php:

```
// Test.php
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar' ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('<?php echo $_SESSION['foo'] ?>');
</scrip>

<?php var_dump($_SESSION['foo']) ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but you can't :(

**First a little Background:**

> Session support in PHP consists of a way to preserve certain data across subsequent accesses. This enables you to build more customized applications and increase the appeal of your web site.
>
> A visitor accessing your web site is assigned a unique id, the so-called session id. This is either stored in a cookie on the user side or is propagated in the URL.
>
> The session support allows you to register arbitrary numbers of variables to be preserved across requests. When a visitor accesses your site, PHP will check automatically (if session.auto_start is set to 1) or on your request (explicitly through session_start() or implicitly through session_register()) whether a specific session id has been sent with the request. If this is the case, the prior saved environment is recreated. 
>   *From http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php*

Basically Sessions involve storing data server side and storing an ID in a cookie client side. Meaning that JS could in theory access the cookie but then all you would have would be access to the PHPSESSID variable (the session id).

To achieve what you are trying to do, you can use ajax. (Contrary to the popular misconception) ajax requests still provide the server with all the information it needs to access cookies and sessions.

So simply make a server side script like `getName.php` which contains:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['name'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['name'];
}
```

And use ajax to get the response :)

Comment: Or just do what Digital Precision said and skip the AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

well ... ajax is nice and everything, but if you really want, you can just print them as variables in your  tag in the head and access them via js that way. I've never done that with session variables, but I print out values from php (mysql) in that manner all the time

Comment: I wouldn't use this for any sort of secure/private data.  The client can't directly access session variables, but if you send them to javascript and then use logic there to, say, authenticate people, you can run into problems. it's very easy to "fake" javascript variables, so you can't count on them being 100% accurate

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to access session variables made in php from javascript

No. They reside in the memory of your web server to which, fortunately, javascript has no access.

Answer (score 0):

Session variables are stored on the server.  The only way to access them with javascript (which is client side) would be to make a request to the backend with AJAX to a php page which would then return the value to you.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant. Session variables are stored in the server, not in the client. The closest thing you can do is verify the session variable in a php script and call it with ajax.